# Nested JSON Values cause "TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

Would love some help here. Full context this is my first "purposeful" Python script. Prior to this I've only dabbled a bit and am honestly still learning so maybe I jumped in a bit too early here.

Long story short, been running all over fixing various type mismatches or just general indentation issues (dear lord python isn't forgiving on this).

I think I'm about finished but have a few last issues. Most of them seem to come from the same section too. This script is just mean to get a csv file that has 3 columns and use that to send requests based on the first column (either iOS or Android). The problem is when I'm creating the body to send...
Here's the code (a few tokens omitted for postability):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from datetime import *
import uuid
import warnings
from math import isnan
import time


## throttling based on AF's 80 request per 2 minute rule
def throttle():
    i = 0
    while i <= 3:
        print ("PAUSED FOR THROTTLING!" + "\n" + str(3-i) + " minutes remaining")
        time.sleep(60)
        i = i + 1
        print (i)
    return 0

## function for reformating the dates
def date():
    d = datetime.utcnow()  # # <-- get time in UTC
    d = d.isoformat('T') + 'Z'
    t = d.split('.')
    t = t[0] + 'Z'
    return str(t)


## function for dealing with Android requests
def android_request(madv_id,mtime,muuid,android_app,token,endpoint):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

    params = {'api_token': token }

    subject_identities = {
        "identity_format": "raw",
        "identity_type": "android_advertising_id", 
        "identity_value": madv_id
    }

    body = {
        'subject_request_id': muuid,
        'subject_request_type': 'erasure',
        'submitted_time': mtime,
        'subject_identities': dict(subject_identities),
        'property_id': android_app
        }
    body = json.dumps(body)
    res = requests.request('POST', endpoint, headers=headers,
                           data=body, params=params)
    print("android " + res.text)

## function for dealing with iOS requests
def ios_request(midfa, mtime, muuid, ios_app, token, endpoint):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json'}
    params = {'api_token': token}

    subject_identities = {
        'identity_format': 'raw',
        'identity_type': 'ios_advertising_id',
        'identity_value': midfa,
    }
    body = {
        'subject_request_id': muuid,
        'subject_request_type': 'erasure',
        'submitted_time': mtime,
        'subject_identities': list(subject_identities),
        'property_id': ios_app,
        }

    body = json.dumps(body)
    res = requests.request('POST', endpoint, headers=headers, data=body, params=params)
    print("ios " + res.text)

## main run function. Determines whether it is iOS or Android request and sends if not LAT-user
def run(output, mdf, is_test):

  # # assigning variables to the columns I need from file

    print ('Sending requests! Stand by...')
    platform = mdf.platform
    device = mdf.device_id

    if is_test=="y":
        ios = 'id000000000'
        android = 'com.tacos.okay'
        token = 'OMMITTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW_Q'
        endpoint = 'https://hq1.appsflyer.com/gdpr/stub'
    else:
        ios = 'id000000000'
        android = 'com.tacos.best'
        token = 'OMMITTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW_Q'
        endpoint = 'https://hq1.appsflyer.com/gdpr/opengdpr_requests'


    for position in tqdm(range(len(device))):
        if position % 80 == 0 and position != 0: 
            throttle()
        else:
            req_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            timestamp = str(date())

            if platform[position] == 'android' and device[position] != '':
                android_request(device[position], timestamp, req_id, android, token, endpoint)
                mdf['subject_request_id'][position] = req_id

            if platform[position] == 'ios' and device[position] != '':
                ios_request(device[position], timestamp, req_id, ios, token, endpoint)
                mdf['subject_request_id'][position] = req_id

            if 'LAT' in platform[position]:
                mdf['subject_request_id'][position] = 'null'
                mdf['error status'][position] = 'Limit Ad Tracking Users Unsupported. Device ID Required'

            mdf.to_csv(output, sep=',', index = False, header=True)
        # mdf.close()

    print ('\nDONE. Please see ' + output 
        + ' for the subject_request_id and/or error messages\n')

## takes the CSV given by the user and makes a copy of it for us to use
def read(mname):
    orig_csv = pd.read_csv(mname)
    mdf = orig_csv.copy()

    # Check that both dataframes are actually the same
    # print(pd.DataFrame.equals(orig_csv, mdf))

    return mdf

## just used to create the renamed file with _LOGS.csv
def rename(mname):
    msuffix = '_LOG.csv'
    i = mname.split('.')
    i = i[0] + msuffix
    return i

## adds relevant columns to the log file
def logs_csv(out, df):
    mdf = df
    mdf['subject_request_id'] = ''
    mdf['error status'] = ''
    mdf['device_id'].fillna('')
    mdf.to_csv(out, sep=',', index=None, header=True)

    return mdf

## solely for reading in the file name from the user. creates string out of filename
def readin_name():
    mprefix = input('FILE NAME: ')
    msuffix = '.csv'
    mname = str(mprefix + msuffix)
    print ('\n' + 'Reading in file: ' + mname)
    return mname

def start():
    print ('\nWelcome to GDPR STREAMLINE')
    # # blue = OpenFile()
    testing = input('Is this a test? (y/n) : ')

    # return a CSV
    name = readin_name()
    import_csv = read(name)
    output_name = rename(name)

    output_file = logs_csv(output_name, import_csv)

    run( output_name, output_file, testing)


  # # print ("FILE PATH:" + blue)

## to disable all warnings in console logs

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
start()
```

And here's the error stacktrace:

```
Reading in file: test.csv
Sending requests! Stand by...
  0%|                                                                                                                                                        | 0/384 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a_GDPR_delete.py", line 199, in <module>
    start()
  File "a_GDPR_delete.py", line 191, in start
    run( output_name, output_file, testing)
  File "a_GDPR_delete.py", line 114, in run
    android_request(device[position], timestamp, req_id, android, token, endpoint)
  File "a_GDPR_delete.py", line 57, in android_request
    body = json.dumps(body)
  File "/Users/joseph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/Users/joseph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Users/joseph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Users/joseph/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable
```

---

***TL;DR:***
Getting a typeError when calling this on a JSON with another nested JSON. I've confirmed that the nested JSON is the problem because if I remove the "subject_identities" section this compiles and works...but the API I'm using NEEDS those values so this doesn't actually do anything without that section.

Here's the relevant code again (and in the version I first used that WAS working previously):

```
def android (madv_id, mtime, muuid):
  headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json"
  }
  params = {
      "api_token": "OMMITTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW_Q"
  }
  body = {
     "subject_request_id": muuid, #muuid, 
     "subject_request_type": "erasure", 
     "submitted_time": mtime, 
     "subject_identities": [
        { "identity_type": "android_advertising_id", 
           "identity_value": madv_id, 
           "identity_format": "raw" }
        ], 
     "property_id": "com.tacos.best" 

  } 
  body = json.dumps(body) 
  res = requests.request("POST", 
  "https://hq1.appsflyer.com/gdpr/opengdpr_requests", 
  headers=headers, data=body, params=params)
```

I get the feeling I'm close to this working. I had a much simpler version early on that worked but I rewrote this to be more dynamic and use less hard coded values (so that I can eventually use this to apply to any app I'm working with an not only the two it was made for).

Please be nice, I'm entirely new to python and also just rusty on coding in general (thus trying to do projects like this one)

Comment: This is an aside, but what is the point of your `def read(mname):` function? Why do you create a copy, and return a copy? Nothing ever happens with the original.

Comment: Anyway, `device[position]` that you pass here: `android_request(device[position], timestamp, req_id, android, token, endpoint)` returns an `np.int64` object, which `json` wont recognize as json serializable. Just convert it to an int, so `int(device[position])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga for the read(), from what I saw, this script ends up editing the original CSV I get which I didn't want to occur. This was me trying to create a new copy and only use that moving forward.

Also, you other answer you gave would work but needed one adjustment as the values in that function aren't actually integers. 

I'm passing are IDs like so "ab12ab12-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234abcd5678" so iI had to use
    android_request(str(device[position]), timestamp, req_id, android, token, endpoint)

Comment: Modifications to the data-frame returned by `read_csv` won't modify the csv file. If that is happening, `.copy` won't stop it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ahh, good to know. I was actually seeing this on my end. Could that have just been me using the incorrect file name in my `to_csv()` call?

Comment: could have been, sure

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga found it. Also updated that. I was able to entirely remove that `read()` method based on your feedback. Thanks so much for the help here!

Wasn't sure if this was gonna work about but stackOverflow never fails. I should've known better

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `numpy` dtypes like so:

```
if hasattr(obj, 'dtype'):
    obj = obj.item()
```

This will convert it to the closest equivalent data type

EDIT:
Apparently `np.nan` is JSON serializable so I've removed that catch from my answer

Comment: Um, why are you doing that with `np.isnan`? `float('nan')` will return true, but `NaN` is JSON serializable

Comment: I've seen json errors thrown when trying to insert `float` converted `nan` into documentDB, if it *is* serializable, then I can remove it

Comment: try: `print(json.dumps({'a':float('nan')}))`

Comment: You're right, works with `json.dumps({"a": np.nan})` as well. Thanks for the catch

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 
Thanks to both of you. Good to know moving forward. Appreciate the assistance.
I was able to fix it with the above from juanpa.arrivillaga (above) but will definitely check both of these and see if anything differs.
<3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for helping so quickly here. Apparently I was deceived by the error message as the fix from @juanpa.arrivillaga did the job with one adjustment.

Corrected code was on these parts:
`android_request(str(device[position]), timestamp, req_id, android, token, endpoint)`

and here:
`ios_request(str(device[position]), timestamp, req_id, ios, token, endpoint)`

I had to cast to string apparently even though these values are not originally integers and tend to look like this instead `ab12ab12-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234abcd5678`